# What does "Bool-var" mean in "In the Midst of Alarms"?

Tags: meaning, robert-barr, in-the-midst-of-alarms

In *[In the Midst of Alarms](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/9263/9263-h/9263-h.htm#link2HCH0013)* (1894) by Robert Barr, Yates was defeated in a friendly fight by his friend, professor Renmark, and he was astonished by the fighting skill of this quiet educated professor

> Oh, I say, Renny, that wasn’t fair. That was a kick.”
>
> “No, it wasn’t. It is merely a little French touch. I learned it in Paris. They do kick there, you know; and it is good to know how to use your feet as well as your fists if you are set on by three, as I was one night in the Latin Quarter.”
>
> Yates sat up.
>
> “Look here, Renmark; when were you in Paris?”
>
> “Several times.”
>
> Yates gazed at him for a few moments, then said:
>
> “Renny, you improve on acquaintance. I never saw **a Bool-var** in my life. You must teach me that little kick.

What does a "Bool-var" mean here?

Comment: I saw the title of the question and thought it meant "Boolean variable", but the year disabused me of that notion

Comment: @CopperKettle Since [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) variables are named after George Boole, who established boolean logic in [1847](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole#Symbolic_logic), and died [December 1864](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole), 30 years before _In the Midst of Alarms_ was published, and seeing that lady Ada Lovelace wrote what is now regarded as the first computer program (note the variables in the photo!) in [1842](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace#First_computer_program), your disabusement can now be disabused!

Comment: ...although it was my first thought as well! Guess boolean variables weren't in common use by the man in the street in Paris in the 1890s though 

Comment: @ReversedEngineer They're not in common use by the man in the street in Paris (or anywhere else) today!  Sure, I know a lot of us here are programmers, so of course we all know that term, but average folks probably don't.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The spelling "Bool-var" is an attempt to render the French pronunciation of [boulevard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boulevard#Pronunciation_4), in which the 'e' in the middle and the 'd' at the end are silent: `/bul.vaʁ/` (in IPA). In the [English pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boulevard#English), the 'e' and the 'd' are not silent: `/ˈbuː.ləˌvɑːd/` or `/ˈbʊləvɑɹd/`.

There are many well-known [boulevards in Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulevards_of_Paris), such as the [Boulevard Haussmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulevard_Haussmann) and the [Boulevard des Italiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulevard_des_Italiens).